# Question with cups!

Tags: probability, combinatorics

OK this is a homework question, but I'm really having troubles and in need for help.

I have 6 cups of different sizes and 6 plates when each plate suits one cup.

If we randomly place the cups on the plates (one cup on each plate) what is the probability that -

A. Exactly 4 cups will be placed on their plates.

B. The two smallest cups will be placed on their plates.

C. The three smallest cups will be placed on the three biggest cups' plates.

D. Exactly one cup will be placed on its plate.

Thanks!

Comment: I have $6nCr4$ possibilities to place all the cups on their plates. SO to place excactly 4 cups on their place I just divide all possibilities by the limited possibilities, which is $4/15$(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $6!$ ways of arranging the cups relative to the plates.

A. How many ways can you place exactly 4 cups in their plates.  How many ways can you misplace exactly 2 cups relative to their plates?

B, There's only one way to place the two smallest cups on their plates. How many ways are there to arrange the rest?

C. How many ways can you place the three smallest cups in the three largest plates?  How many ways can you arrange the rest?

D. How many ways can you arrange the rest of the cups so they do not end up on their respective plates?

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Can you elaborate on D?

Comment: There are 6 ways to place that one cup on its correct plate.  You must then count the number of ways that you can place the other cups on any other plate but its own.